# Kettle 5.0 not recognizing Number datatype, when accessed from Oracle

Tags: kettle

We recently upgraded pentaho kettle from 4.0 to 5.0. In our kettle job we are accessing few columns from Oracle of type Number(10) but it throws error now. Only when we cast it, then it works

earlier "select id...from table a " (can't access now)
now "select to_number(id) ...from table a "

1. What is bignumber datatype ?
2. We have so many jobs. Where can we find detailed tech specifications for ver 5.0 ( i mean if anything depreciated etc or variables, datatype changes

Thanks

Comment: just sounds like a bug to me. They changed data types a LOT in PDI5 - introduction of proper timestamps, and pluggable data types, seems like this is a regression.  Probably worth raising a jira assuming you've tried the latest CI version.